# How to make qml tab order navigation?

Tags: qt, tabs, qml

How to make tab order navigation in QML

For example I have such code:

```
TextInput { id: one }
TextInput { id: two }
TextInput { id: three }
```

And I need on pressing tab from focus on "one" move to "three", haven't found that in official documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
TextInput {
  id: one
  KeyNavigation.tab: three
}
```

Key navigation in QML is documented at this page and provide some example at:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.5/qml-qtquick-keynavigation.html

Comment: Hmm strange a thought it's not for tab navigation, but for controling.